# Submit form using curl php

Tags: php, curl, sms

I am trying to send SMS through a website using a PHP script and here is the code

```
function send_sms($phone,$message)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.fullonsms/home.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)       AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107     Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "MobileNos=".$phone."&message=".$message);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');  
    $text=curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
}
send_sms("1234567890","hi");
```

I have already made an account on this website www.fullonsms.com and now I am trying to send text message using my account. The ID of the form elements are MobileNos and message. Can you please tell me why this is not working. Am I missing something or is this completely wrong approach?

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Since you have an account don't you have to give it your credentials? Also you are missing TLD on `http://www.fullonsms/home.php`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the rest, you need to look closely how request are processed and on what page it's sending requests, as you're posting stuff to `home.php`

So, before that, you need to login into system using `curl`. I'm providing you head start with sample function, that will login to system and will set `cookie`.

```
function login($username,$password)
{
    $username = urlencode($username);
    $password = urlencode($password);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.fullonsms.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)       AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107     Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "MobileNoLogin=$username&LoginPassword=$password&captcha_val=10");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');   // cookie now set with logged in stuff. 
    $text=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
    //return $text; return and echo text if you want to view logged in page.
}
```

call this function before `send_sms(...)`.

```
login(...);
```

also in your code, you're not posting stuff to right page.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.fullonsms/home.php');
```

it should be like **after log in(*obvious*)**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.fullonsms.com/home.php');
```